# Is it possible to have an :after pseudo element on a button?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a button and on a `:hover` I would like an after element to show. But I can't see it. Is it possible to have an `:after` element on a button?

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
}

.button-primary {
  border: none;
}

.button-primary:hover:after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button-primary">My button</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget `content:"";` in your `:after`.

Comment: @BeatAlex This is the answer why the pseudo element doesn't show up.

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the snippet @feeela

Comment: @BeatAlex might be just a copy/paste mistake, as this is SASS syntax and there are maybe much more definitions before the original closing bracket. Good hint nonetheless.

Comment: Ah yeah he commented on my answer anyway telling me it was just a mistake! :)

Comment: Make sure you watch what element you're actually using.  The button element should allow it, but other *replaced* elements like input, img, textarea, select, etc. do not.

Comment: This is still an interesting question - Chrome adds the :after pseudo Element before the end tag of the button, and not after it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should now work on all up to date browsers.

To get it to work, you need to add `content:"";` in your `after`.

Comment: Do you know on which browser it doesn't work? I just tried on browserstack a fiddle, and it seems that every browser that support pseudo elements accept it on `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it – as long as you as don't need to support some very old browsers, e.g. MS IE 7 or lower. I don't know of any other browser that doesn't understand pseudo elements on empty HTML tags. In fact I already used it in several production sites without any problems.