# CSS after is dropped when button changes to ASP Button

Tags: css, asp.net

Query:

How can I keep the 'after' part of the code working when I change the html button to an ASP button. I'm not sure why it drops?

Issue:

When I change `<button` to `<asp:button` the after part of the CSS no longer works. The part of the code that fails is `#course .bottom .btn-next:after`

Code:

```
#course .bottom .next {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#course .bottom .btn-next {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
#course .bottom .btn-next:after {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Research example:

[Is it possible to have a :after pseudo element on a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767633/is-it-possible-to-have-a-after-pseudo-element-on-a-button) (relates to html not .NET button)

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Edited: How can I keep the 'after' part of the code working when I change the html button to an ASP button. I'm not sure why it drops?

Comment: A potential solution is: <a href="#" class="btn btn-next">   <asp:button ID="btnNext" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-next" text="Next"/> </a>     but I'd prefer to keep as just a button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an asp .net button renders and input with a `type="submit"`.

You could render it as follows (please note without your markup I am taking a guess):

```
<button runat="server" id="btnId" class="btn btn-next">
    Dooz it
</button>
```

This will render it as a button tag but notice the `runat="server"` which makes it an HTML server control.

Comment: That looks good, how can it then action something in the .NET? i.e. on the click go to  Protected Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click on the .vb part of the code. (time for a new question?)

Comment: @indofraiser You can use `OnServerClick=` with the name of your method i.e. `OnServerClick=btn_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

I've currently used the following, now perfect but CSS and link works:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-next">
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-next" Text="Next" /></a>
```