# Looking for the best way to add an icon to a button on css

Tags: css

I have a value input. We need to add an icon. What's the best way to do this?

```
<input type="button" class="upload" value="Choose File" />`
```

Now I'm adding  positioning absolute:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 115px;
  top: 55px;                
}
```

```
<img src="/media/colour/group.png" alt="icon" title="arrow icon" />
```

[image]

Comment: you can add the image using background-image for example, if you make some search you can find a lot of tutorials about it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767633/is-it-possible-to-have-an-after-pseudo-element-on-a-button

Comment: You can use a `<button>` element instead. In contrast to the input type button it can have (HTML) content. Also, why is your input not an `<input type="file">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
input[type='button'] {
    background-image: url(/media/colour/group.png);
    background-position: 7px 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: this won't work, he has type button, your selector is type='text' ;)

Comment: add some explanation, because 7px 7px for positioning background isn'a good choice